# Why history.length is 2 for the first page?

Tags: javascript

If I open a new browser window and open a new page in it `history.length` is 2 in both Chrome and Firefox. Does anyone know why?

Test page: http://jsbin.com/amiyaw

Comment: I just opened the link in a new tab and got 1 (In firefox), and i'm guessing chrome must treat it's start page as a page.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's because the new tab, or window, has a default page, which also counts as history. In Chrome's case, it's the apps/most visited page.

If you open it from a link, and thus not opening the "new tab" page inbetween, it will output 1.

Comment: so how can we do validation check on these 2 scenarios?