# Create helper function for a (click handler) function to reuse in multiple React components

Tags: reactjs, function, onclick, react-component

For a 'back' button I've created below (onClick) handler function in my React app.

```
  const { length: historyLength, goBack, replace } = useHistory();

  const handleBack = () => {
    if (historyLength > 2) {
      goBack();
    } else {
      // History length is 2 by default when nothing is pushed to history yet
      // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564041/why-history-length-is-2-for-the-first-page
      replace(HomePage);
    }
  };
```

Then I am passing the onClick handler to my child component like: `<Button onClick={handleBack}/>`

I am using this `handleBack` function in multiple places in my React app. Is it a good approach make it e.g. a helper function and how exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also don't see any issue with the code or using it as a utility callback.

> Is it a good approach make it e.g. a helper function and how exactly?

Anytime you can make your code more ***DRY*** (*Don't Repeat Yourself*) it's generally a good thing. My personal rule-of-thumb is if I've written the same utility code a third time I'll spend a bit of time to refactor it into a common utility (*and unit test!!*).

I might suggest creating a custom hook to return the back handler.

Example:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const useBackHandler = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleBack = React.useCallback(() => {
    const { length: historyLength, goBack, replace } = history;

    if (historyLength > 2) {
      goBack();
    } else {
      replace(HomePage);
    }
  }, []);

  return handleBack;
};

export default useBackHandler;
```

Now you have a single hook to import and use.

```
import useBackHandler from '../path/to/useBackHandler';

...

const backHandler = useBackHandler();

...

<button type="button" onClick={backHandler}>Back?</button>
```

If you are needing this function in older class components, then you'll need a way to inject the `handleBack` as a prop. For this you can create a Higher Order Component.

Example:

```
import useBackHandler from '../path/to/useBackHandler';

const withBackHandler = Component => props => {
  const backHandler = useBackHandler();
  return <Component {...props} backHandler={backHandler} />;
};

export default withBackHandler;
```

To use, import `withBackHandler` and decorate a React component and access `props.backHandler`.

```
import withBackHandler from '../path/to/withBackHandler';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  ...

  someFunction = () => {
    ...
    this.props.backHandler();
  }

  ...
}

export default withBackHandler(MyComponent);
```

Comment: @meez `useCallback` was used to memoize the `handleBack` function to provide a stable reference to consumers. React hooks can only be called inside React function components and other custom hooks. It sounds like you are not using `useBackHandler` in a function component. Are you needing to use this with older class components?

Comment: thanks, no I am using only functional components

Comment: @meez I see, then you might've just been calling `useBackHandler` outside a React component (*or some other breaking of the Rules of Hooks*), though, if there was an issue using the `useCallback` hook I would expect a similar issue trying to use the `useHistory` hook as well. Can you share what/how you were trying to use the solution I proposed?

Comment: Error is gone. Before I compiled again etc and rebooted the server etc. Working fine never mind

Comment: @meez Roger. Thanks for confirming it's working for you now as expected. Cheers.

Comment: last thing. I try to get my head around the `useCallback` hook. Can you maybe explain it a bit more? It's still a bit vague to me. I read some documentation but it's hard to understand. Thanks a lot

Comment: @meez The basic gist is that it just memoizes a function so it has a stable reference across React render cycles. Oftentimes functions are passed to or consumed by children components and if the callback wasn't a stable reference it can trigger unnecessary rerenders. It's an optimization tool.

Answer (score 0):

@meez

Don't see why this wouldn't work. Just a couple of things: (a) I would add the event argument and `e.preventDefault()` within the function and (b) would be careful of the function name you are passing on the `onClick` property of your button: `handleBackClick !== handleBack`, you'll get an ReferenceError because of an undefined function.

Additionally, I also noticed that this can be achieved with native browser functions. Here's a snippet:

```js
const { length: historyLength, back } = window.history;
const { replace } = window.location;

const handleBack = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (historyLength > 2) {
    back();
  } else {
    replace('homepageUrl');
  }
};
```

Comment: why should you use a native browser function instead of using the React hook `useHistory()`? Also my question is not really about this function, but about how to reuse it in multiple components.

Comment: Don't use the native browser functions if you want the routing context from `react-router` to know about the navigation actions.